# Is partial mocking of a security a good practice?

Tags: mocking, nsubstitute, regression-testing, ninject-mockingkernel

I am introducing automatic testing using NUnit, NSubstitute for a project which uses Ninject and generic repositories.

For regression testing, I am replacing generic repositories with in memory ones to prevent working with a database.

Also, to test security constraints of services, I am mocking the security service which looks like this:

```
public class SecurityService : ISecurityService
{
    #region Properties
    private IScopedDataAccess DataAccess { get; }
    private IMappingService MappingService { get; }
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public SecurityService(IScopedDataAccess scopedDataAccess, IMappingService mappingService)
    {
        DataAccess = scopedDataAccess;
        MappingService = mappingService;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods
    public virtual string GetUsername()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    }

    public AppUserSecurityProfileServiceModel GetCurrentUserData()
    {
        var username = GetUsername();
        var userDataModel = DataAccess.AppUserRepository.AllNoTracking.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == username);
        if (userDataModel == null)
            return null;

        var ret = MappingService.Mapper.Map<AppUserSecurityProfileServiceModel>(userDataModel);
        return ret;
    }

    public virtual int GetCurrentUserId()
    {
        var userData = GetCurrentUserData();
        if (userData == null)
            throw new SecurityException($"No user data could be fetched for - {GetUsername()}");

        return userData.AppUserId;
    }

    public bool IsInRole(UserRoleEnum role, int? userId = null)
    {
        int actualUserId = userId ?? GetCurrentUserId();

        var hasRole = DataAccess.AppUserXUserRoleRepository.AllNoTracking.Any(x => x.AppUserId == actualUserId && x.UserRoleId == (int) role);
        return hasRole;
    }

    public bool CanPerformAction(UserActionEnum action, int? userId = null)
    {
        int actualUserId = userId ?? GetCurrentUserId();

        var hasAction = DataAccess.AppUserXUserRoleRepository.AllNoTracking
            .Where(x => x.AppUserId == actualUserId)
            .Join(DataAccess.UserRoleRepository.AllNoTracking, xRole => xRole.UserRoleId, role => role.UserRoleId, (xRole, role) => role)
            .Join(DataAccess.UserRoleXUserActionRepository.AllNoTracking, xRole => xRole.UserRoleId, xAction => xAction.UserRoleId,
                (role, xAction) => xAction.UserActionId)
            .Contains((int) action);

        return hasAction;
    }

    // other methods can appear here in the future
    #endregion
}
```

Each regression test fakes current user like this:

```
public void FakeCurrentUser(int userId)
{
    var userRef = DataAccess.AppUserRepository.AllNoTracking.FirstOrDefault(u => u.AppUserId == userId);

    var securitySubstitude = Substitute.ForPartsOf<SecurityService>(Kernel.Get<IScopedDataAccess>(), Kernel.Get<IMappingService>());

    securitySubstitude.When(x => x.GetUsername()).DoNotCallBase();
    securitySubstitude.GetUsername().Returns(userRef?.Username ?? "<none>");
    securitySubstitude.When(x => x.GetCurrentUserId()).DoNotCallBase();
    securitySubstitude.GetCurrentUserId().Returns(userId);

    Kernel.Rebind<ISecurityService>().ToConstant(securitySubstitude);
}
```

Basically, it takes care to replace methods that are based on the context (i.e. `HttpContext` in my case), but leaves other method intact.

Each tested service will be instantiated after this initialization, so I am sure that the appropriate instance is injected.

**Question: is it OK to mock the service like this or is it an anti-pattern?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a particular concern with this approach? It seems workable in this case.

Personally I like to avoid partial mocks because then I have to keep a more careful track on which parts are real / going to call real code vs which parts are faked out. If you have the flexibility to change the code here, you could push the `HttpContext` related stuff to another dependency (Strategy pattern I think) and then fake that out instead.

Something like:

```
public interface IUserInfo {
    string GetUsername();
    int GetCurrentUserId();
}

public class HttpContextUserInfo : IUserInfo {
    public string GetUsername() { return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name; }
    public int GetCurrentUserId() { ... }
}

public class SecurityService : ISecurityService
{
    private IScopedDataAccess DataAccess { get; }
    private IMappingService MappingService { get; }
    // New field:
    private IUserInfo UserInfo { get; }

    // Added ctor argument:
    public SecurityService(IScopedDataAccess scopedDataAccess, IMappingService mappingService, IUserInfo userInfo)
    { ... }

    public AppUserSecurityProfileServiceModel GetCurrentUserData()
    {
        var username = UserInfo.GetUsername();
        var userDataModel = DataAccess.AppUserRepository.AllNoTracking.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == username);
        ...
        return ret;
    }

    public bool IsInRole(UserRoleEnum role, int? userId = null)
    {
        int actualUserId = userId ?? UserInfo.GetCurrentUserId();
        var hasRole = ...;
        return hasRole;
    }

    public bool CanPerformAction(UserActionEnum action, int? userId = null)
    {
        int actualUserId = userId ?? UserInfo.GetCurrentUserId();
        var hasAction = ...;
        return hasAction;
    }    
}
```

Now you're free to pass in an alternate implementation of `IUserInfo` for your test (can implement by hand or use a mocking library). This addresses my initial concern with partial mocks because I know that all of the `SecurityService` being tested is calling its real code, and I can manipulate the test dependencies to exercise different parts of that code. The cost is that we now have another class to worry about (and potentially another interface; I've used one but you could stick to a single class with virtual methods) which increases the complexity of the solution a little.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I can make any changes in the code. Having a separate dependency is a very good idea, since I will mock exactly what is generating the context. Anything else in the security dependency can be "real". Thanks.